# How to execute .bat file based another .bat file execution completion?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have two .bat files. lets call them first.bat and second.bat.
Upon executing first.bat file, a Selenium (node) automation script execution will start and export console outputs to text file.

Since export console out to text file is happening after completion of first bat file, I'm not able to send console output to slack channel. I have created second bat file(it will invoke JavaScript) for sending console out to slack channel.

How do I execute the second bat file based on the first bat file execution? I'm planning to put in schedule.

Comment: Is there some code you can show us? In the meantime, please read the following documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
@ echo off
:begin
set /p number=What Number?

if %number% EQU 1 goto :END

goto :Error

:End
start OtherThing.bat
exit

:Error
echo didn't finish
goto :begin
```